# Mocking service module Variables dependencies for Angular unit testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, variables, service, mocking

I have an angular service that I am writing unit tests for and one of the methods I am testing uses module variables from external dependencies that I am mocking and injecting in a BeforeEach before the test is run. These variables are either just standard arrays or JSON and in the original function, they are accessed based off the outputs off service dependency methods.

I've mocked the methods using jasmine createSpy and callFake and I tried mocking the values of these variables in the same way but they are coming back as undefined and the test fails as a result.

What would be the best approach to mock the values of these variables?

The variables are defined for example like this:

```
var module = {
   variableOne= [ a, b , c];
   variableTwo = {1, 2, 3};
};
```

and then the service method that I am testing calls them by eg:

```
DependentService.variableOne[outputOfMockedDependencyMethod];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your tests, when you inject the service, you can then change it :

```
it(
  'your desc',
  inject([YourService], (service: YourService) => {
    service.mockedValue = {/* all you want */};
  }));
```

Comment: Is this in the inject for the service that I am testing or for the dependency services ? Atm I have a separate inject for dependencies inside my beforeEach . If it is the for the service I am testing, does it matter that the variables are coming from the external dependencies?

Comment: Well you asked for help on your service unit testing. And if you do it in the beforeEach, then you can do the same thing I show here ! I tend to do it directly in the test case, because I usually give several mocks to my services ( to test every possible outcome)